# Expo react native not using plugin defined in babel.config.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, expo

So I am using minimal workflow with Typescript and I have this in `babel.config.js`,

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true)
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            [
                "module-resolver",
                {
                    root: ["."],
                    alias: {
                        "lib/": "./"
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to alias path. But it's not working at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to clear cache. `yarn ios -- -c`